# PHP & MySQL Table Report with a variable number of columns

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Has anyone attempted or seen something like this before?

My PHP/MySQL knowledge is non-existent, though a friend assures me this would be pretty easy to do (although he has yet to make any suggestions about how to approach it...).  The information I have is that this is a custom PHP build.

Also, I have searched a variety of help sites, however, without finding any examples of 
code that could render a table from MySQL data that would allow the number of columns to fluxuate with the number of comma-delimited inputs in a field.  So, here goes:

Using Gravity Forms v. 1.8.4, I have created a 40 item checkbox in field 4 of form 17, which appears on post 136 in WordPress 3.8.1.  Users of the site are instructed to select exactly 7 of the 40 items.  The selections are stored in the WordPress/MySQL table called, wp_rg_lead_detail, and are grouped by lead ID (which varies) and form ID (which is always 17).

In GF form 22, which appears on WP post 87:

- first, users select from a dropdown menu (called field ID 2), the value "Shared Values Results" and,
- then, in a single line text box (called field ID 3), users submit a series of common delimited numerals representing the user ID numbers of each user whose values will be compared in the resulting report.  For example, a value of "1, 23, 95, 184" in field ID 3, form 22, should result in a report comparing the 7 items selected from field 4, form 17, for each of userID 1, userID 23, userID 95, and userID 184.

Now, I need to produce a report, which will appear on post 174.  The layout should be a table, 41 rows by 3 or more columns, with the following parameters:

The first row will be a header containing the word "Values" in Row 1, Column 1, and the selected userIDs in each of Row 1, Columns 2, 3, etc.  Rows 2-41 of Column 1 will be populated by each of the 40 items from checkbox at field 4, form 17.  In Rows 2-41 of Columns 2, 3, etc., one "X" should appear in each cell that represents one of the 7 items selected by each user.

In our example, there would be 4 columns in addition to Column 1 (although the number of columns would vary depending on the number of user IDs provided for comparison).  The result might look like this:

```
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'      Values   ''   1   ''   23   ''   95   ''  184   '
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Collaboration  ''   X   ''        ''        ''   X    ' 
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Networking     ''       ''    X   ''        ''   X    ' 
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Independence   ''   X   ''        ''    X   ''   X    '
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Security       ''       ''    X   ''        ''        '
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Control        ''   X   ''    X   ''    X   ''   X    '
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Compromise     ''   X   ''        ''    X   ''   X    '
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Winning        ''   X   ''        ''        ''   X    '
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
... etc., thru Row 41/Value # 40 ....
```

If you can point me to some code that I could adapt to this, I would really appreciate it.  My searches to date may have been hampered by not knowing what terminology to use to attain this result.

Comment: Can you please post a sample of the value you get back from MySQL?  If it's something like a comma-separated list, you can probably explode it, count the number of items, then use a `for` loop to spin through it and print out your table data.  Maybe seeing the data that is returned from MySQL will help to determine how to get to the goal.

Comment: See normalization. Unfortunately, the best approach might be an EAV model

Comment: Quixrick, the following is an approximation of what I think you are asking for:

Comment: ...(I would put it into a table, but I can't seem to format in this Response area.) the columns are "id", "lead_id", "form_id", "field_number", "value".  There are 7 rows, one for each of the selected values.  For id # 118, the lead_id is 21, the form_id is 17, the field_number is 4.2, and the value is "Guaranteed income".  For id # 119, lead_id and form_id are the same, field_number is 4.4, and value is "Helping others" and so on....  If that's not what you are looking for, please let me know.

Comment: ...These are the responses associated with UserID 1.  UserID 23, would have a different set of responses for the same form_id 17.  Perhaps, UserID 23 would select field_number 4.11 "Having influence" and field_number 4.15 "Taking measurable risks", etc.